# Are there utilities like Python's `dir()` and `help()` in Go?

Tags: go

With Python, we can use `dir()` and `help()` like this:

```
>>> import random
>>> dir(random)
['BPF', 'LOG4', 'NV_MAGICCONST', 'RECIP_BPF', 'Random', 'SG_MAGICCONST', 'SystemRandom', 'TWOPI', '_BuiltinMethodType', '_MethodType', '_Sequence', '_Set', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_acos', '_bisect', '_ceil', '_cos', '_e', '_exp', '_inst', '_itertools', '_log', '_os', '_pi', '_random', '_sha512', '_sin', '_sqrt', '_test', '_test_generator', '_urandom', '_warn', 'betavariate', 'choice', 'choices', 'expovariate', 'gammavariate', 'gauss', 'getrandbits', 'getstate', 'lognormvariate', 'normalvariate', 'paretovariate', 'randint', 'random', 'randrange', 'sample', 'seed', 'setstate', 'shuffle', 'triangular', 'uniform', 'vonmisesvariate', 'weibullvariate']
>>> help(random.randint)
Help on method randint in module random:

randint(a, b) method of random.Random instance
    Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.
```

Are there utilities like Python's `dir()` and `help()` in Go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seek is [go doc](https://golang.org/cmd/doc/).

```
go doc fmt.Printf
```

Which currently yields the output:

```
package fmt // import "fmt"

func Printf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
    Printf formats according to a format specifier and writes to standard
    output. It returns the number of bytes written and any write error
    encountered.
```

You may also be interested in [godoc](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc), which will generate documentation for anything in your GOPATH, and even run an http server to browse it locally.